# Tilt input mappings by example

Tags: game-builder-garage

I completed the 2nd tutorial game "On a Roll" (ball-rolling maze game) and there is one part about the inputs that I just don't understand.
The tutorial has you create 2 Tilt inputs:

- the first Tilt input nodon, where you configure its Z-axis to connect to the X-port on the Moving Object nodon (the ball); and
- the 2nd Tilt input nodon, where you configure its X-axis to connect to the Z-port on the Moving Object nodon

I'm not understanding the mapping of each Tilt axis to the respective port on the ball. Why is the mapping:

- Z-axis --> X-port
- X-axis --> Z-port

Instead of Z-axis to Z-port, and X-axis to X-port? Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Tilt inputs are similar to the Hinge Connector Nodons, so the following explanation should work for both.

This particular tutorial is in the top down view, so as you look at the Switch screen the X axis runs from left to right, and the Z axis from top to bottom. So inputting to the Moving Nodon's X port will have it move right and left, and to the Z port will move up and down.

For the axes, the most helpful visual image is to imagine a nail stuck through the middle of your Switch in the direction of the axis. So, for the Z axis, imagine a nail driven through your Switch from the top to the bottom (following the axis). Now think about how the Switch can rotate around that nail - it will be able to tilt left and right, but not up and down. Thus tilting around the Z axis would logically make things move left and right - that is, in the X direction. Similarly, rotating around the X axis (tilting up and down) would move things in the Z direction. (From this top down view, rotating around the Y axis would just cause the Switch to spin in place, so the ball wouldn't roll anywhere).